# You can't smoke (here / in here)

Tags: sentence-meaning

You can't smoke (**here** / **in  here**).
What's the need of adding ***in*** before ***here*** here.

Can't only ***here*** suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct, but there are subtle differences between both expressions.

*'here'* simply implies a broader sense of location, and that location is usually implicit in the sentence.

> You can't smoke here.

implies that the person can't smoke in the same location as the speaker, wherever they happen to be.

*'in here'* on the other hand, narrows the scope somewhat, because it refers to a space that can be entered, such as a room or building. Other prepositions that work, depending on context, are *'out*', *'down'*, *'up'*. For example:

> You can't smoke in here.
>
> You can't smoke out here.
>
> You can't smoke up here.
>
> You can't smoke down here.

Answer (score 2):

*In* is added only if the place in question is an enclosed one. That way, it adds weight to the fact that it is, in fact, a closed space. For instance, a room.

If it is an open space, like a ground, *in* should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only using **here** will suffice. As stated, **in** refers to an enclosed area. **In** might be used to imply that smoking is allowed nearby.